# Vertical lollipop plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based on the data and code below, how can I convert the plot to a "vertical lollipop" plot?

On a side note how can I also fix the overlap of the y-axis labels and line as shown below.

Data + code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(scales)

df = read.csv(text="category,pct
Other,0.09
South Asian/South Asian Americans,0.12
Interngenerational/Generational,0.21
S Asian/Asian Americans,0.25
Muslim Observance,0.29
Africa/Pan Africa/African Americans,0.34
Gender Equity,0.34
Disability Advocacy,0.49
European/European Americans,0.52
Veteran,0.54
Pacific Islander/Pacific Islander Americans,0.59
Non-Traditional Students,0.61
Religious Equity,0.64
Caribbean/Caribbean Americans,0.67
Latino/Latina,0.69
Middle Eastern Heritages and Traditions,0.73
Trans-racial Adoptee/Parent,0.76
LBGTQ/Ally,0.79
Mixed Race,0.80
Jewish Heritage/Observance,0.85
International Students,0.87", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",", header=TRUE)
 
gg = ggplot(df, aes(reorder(category, pct), pct))
gg = gg + geom_lollipop(point.colour="steelblue", point.size=3)
gg = gg + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), labels=percent,
                              breaks=seq(0, 1, by=0.2), limits=c(0, 1))
gg = gg + coord_flip()
gg = gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, 
                title="SUNY Cortland Multicultural Alumni survey results",
                subtitle="Ranked by race, ethnicity, home land and orientationnamong the top areas of concern",
                caption="Data from http://stephanieevergreen.com/lollipop/")
gg = gg + theme_minimal(base_family="Arial Narrow")
gg = gg + theme(panel.grid.major.y=element_blank())
gg = gg + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
gg = gg + theme(axis.line.y=element_line(color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15))
gg = gg + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(margin=margin(r=-5, l=0)))
gg = gg + theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(30, 4), "pt"))
gg = gg + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold"))
gg = gg + theme(plot.subtitle=element_text(margin=margin(b=10)))
gg = gg + theme(plot.caption=element_text(size=8, margin=margin(t=10)))

gg
```

Current output:

[image]

Comment: Just remove the `coord_flip` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rotate your x-axis labels using `guides` and `guide_axis` with an `angle` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(scales)
gg = ggplot(df, aes(reorder(category, pct), pct))
gg = gg + geom_lollipop(point.colour="steelblue", point.size=3)
gg = gg + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), labels=percent,
                             breaks=seq(0, 1, by=0.2), limits=c(0, 1))
gg = gg + guides(x = guide_axis(angle = 90)) 
gg = gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, 
               title="SUNY Cortland Multicultural Alumni survey results",
               subtitle="Ranked by race, ethnicity, home land and orientationnamong the top areas of concern",
               caption="Data from http://stephanieevergreen.com/lollipop/")
gg = gg + theme_minimal(base_family="Arial Narrow")
gg = gg + theme(panel.grid.major.y=element_blank())
gg = gg + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
gg = gg + theme(axis.line.y=element_line(color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15))
gg = gg + theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(30, 4), "pt"))
gg = gg + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold"))
gg
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yup looks good but, now the x-axis line is gone!

Comment: @Ed_Gravy, change `axis.line.y` to `axis.line.x` in your `theme`

Comment: Or add `axis.line.x` to have on both x and y axis the line.